# Error while parsing the PDF Document (Pg Entry of Structure Element with MCIDs not set.)

Tags: itext

I am using iTextsharp to create/merge Tagged PDFs.
When I run PDF Accessibility Checker2.0 on the generated PDF, I get following error:
**Error while parsing the PDF Document (Pg Entry of Structure Element with MCIDs not set.)** under PDF syntax as shown below:
[image]
I could not find anything related to this issue online. I checked in : https://taggedpdf.com/508-pdf-help-center/

I need to fix this issue using iTextsharp library but I am not able to fix it manually as well.
Please help me if someone has some idea about how to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

I am adding the code below, I am using to create tagged PDF:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfSourceFile);
iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
PdfCopy writer = new PdfSmartCopy(document, new 
FileStream(pdfDestinationFile, FileMode.Create));
writer.SetTagged();
document.Open();
for (int j = 1; j <= reader.NumberOfPages; j++)
{
    if (reader.GetPageContent(j).Length > 0)
    {
        var page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, j, true);
        writer.AddPage(page);
    }
 }
document.Close();
writer.Close();
reader.Close();
```

I have omitted some lines of logic here.

Comment: Merging PDF/UA documents wasn't supported until iText 7. Since you are still talking about **iTextSharp** instead of about **iText for .NET** (the name changed over two years ago), there is a high chance that you are using an old version of iText that predates PDF/UA support. Unfortunately, you don't provide any information on the version of iText you are using, nor are you sharing any code showing how you are trying to create/merge PDF/UA documents.

Comment: I am using iTextsharp version : 5.5.12.0.  I am updating my question with code for creating tagged PDF

Comment: Please upgrade to iText 7.1.3. All recent iText 5.5 releases are *maintenance* releases for *paying* customers who can't migrate to iText 7 who needed bug fixes provided by iText Group because they have a support contract. Those customers know that, once they need PDF/UA support, they are expected to upgrade to iText 7.